# Redis and docker-compose connect 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, port

I have an existing node application that connects to redis at  `127.0.0.1:6379`. I am unable to change this.

I understand that with docker compose it connects the two services `redis` and `node` and allows them to connect using the `redis` hostname, however I can't change this.

How can I make it so that `redis` is accessible from the `node` application at the `127.0.0.1:6379` host and port?

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    hostname: "127.0.0.1"
  redis-cli:
    image: redis
    links:
      - redis
    command: redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1
```

Here's the output:

```
$ docker-compose run redis-cli
Starting install_redis_1 ... done
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
not connected>
```

Comment: you can install redis server inside node container, and with supervisor you can run two apps inside one container

Comment: i think you cant redirect  easily localhost IP, if you install iptables and create a rule to forward everything from 127.0.0.1 to redis it will work, but the approach is yucky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `network_mode: host` in both containers to make `redis` expose its 6379 on localhost, and make localhost available to `redis-cli`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    network_mode: host
  redis-cli:
    depends_on:
      - redis
    image: redis
    network_mode: host
    command: redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 ping
```

And running it:

```
> docker-compose run redis-cli
Starting dockerredis_redis_1 ... done
PONG
```